# SonarCloud Code Coverage doesn't work with Github Action

Tags: reactjs, cypress, pipeline, sonarcloud, cypress-code-coverage

I tried to pass my code coverage report generated by cypress tests with Github Action, but it arrives at SonarCloud with 0% coverage.
In my pipeline, i get the following warn:

> WARN: Could not resolve 7 file paths in [/github/workspace/coverage/lcov.info]

> WARN: First unresolved path: C:\Users\ferso\OneDrive\Documentos\Faculdade\cypress-test\src\App.jsx (Run in DEBUG mode to get full list of unresolved paths)

I Already tried to use sed ci utility to correct file paths and use sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info, but it didn't works

This is my sonar-project.propertie:

```
sonar.projectKey=fsoupimenta_cypress-test
sonar.organization=fsoupimenta
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.javascript.file.suffixes=.js,.jsx
```

and this is my SonarCloud workflow:

```
      - name: fix code coverage paths
        working-directory: ./coverage
        run: |
          sed -i 's/\/home\/runner\/work\/cypress-test\/cypress-test\//\/github\/workspace\//g' lcov.info
          sed -i 's@'$GITHUB_WORKSPACE'@/github/workspace/@g' lcov.info
          sed -i 's/\/home\/runner\/work\/cypress-test\/cypress-test\//\/github\/workspace\//g' sonar-cloud-reporter.xml
          
      - name: SonarCloud Scan
        uses: SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action@master
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Needed to get PR information, if any
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I fixed this error by adding two properties in sonar.project-properties, staying like this:

```
sonar.projectKey=fsoupimenta_cypress-test
sonar.organization=fsoupimenta
sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=cypress/e2e/spec.cy.js
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
```

You can see [this repository](https://github.com/fsoupimenta/cypress-test) for more information